# I tried to create a nav tag where if you hover over the icons, the title or a content attached appears. but the timing in transition isn't working

Tags: html, css, reactjs

```
  .home-link::after, .contact-link::after, .about-link::after {
    font-size: 2rem;
    text-align: center;
    position: absolute;
    margin-left: -3rem;
    bottom: 0rem;
    transition: all .8s ease-in-out;
}



.home-link:hover::after{
    content: "Home";
    
}

.about-link:hover::after{
    content: "About";
}

.contact-link:hover::after{
    content: "Contact";
}
```

from the above code, i;m trying to write a code whereby when one hover on my home icon, about or contact icon, the contents above becomes visible with a 0.8s transition. here the content appears when I hover on the icons but it,s not taking 0.8s to transition.

Answer (score 0):

```
.home-link::after{
    content: "Home";
    font-size: 2rem;
    text-align: center;
    position: absolute;
    margin-left: -3rem;
    bottom: 0rem;
    transition: all .8s ease-in-out;
    opacity:0;
}
.home-link:hover::after{
    opacity: 1;
}
```

if you want your text to slowly fade in you have to use opacity, otherwise the browser will have nothing to work with